# How to stop a random node error: '(node:196569) Warning: An error event has already been emitted on the socket.'

Tags: node.js, express, https

I have an express web server built in node.js. When I run my server, eventually I get the following error in the terminal:

```
(node:196569) Warning: An error event has already been emitted on the socket. Please use the destroy method on the socket while handling a 'clientError' event.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

I am using node:https to create the server as follows:

```
const express = require('express');
const https = require('node:https');

// setting up express
const app = express();

// Setting up SSL Certificates
const https_options = {
    key: process.env.HUTCHYBOP_KEY.replace(/\\n/g, '\n'),
    cert: process.env.CRT_CODE.replace(/\\n/g, '\n'),
    keepAlive: false
};

... rest of my code, routes ect...


// http server (Port 80, should redirect to https);
app.listen(80);

// https Server (Port 443)
https.createServer(https_options, app).listen(443, () => {
    console.log('Server listening on PORT 443 (https)');
    serveHTTP() // logging function
});
```

After doing some reading, I added the keepAlive option hoping it might solve the issue, it did not.

I have added the --trace-warnings option and got:

```
(node:230020) Warning: An error event has already been emitted on the socket. Please use the destroy method on the socket while handling a 'clientError' event.
    at warnUnclosedSocket (node:_http_server:827:11)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnError (node:_http_server:841:5)
    at onParserExecuteCommon (node:_http_server:876:19)
    at onParserExecute (node:_http_server:797:3)
```

I have had a google round for solutions to the error but have come up short and I'm fairly new to this so I'm now stuggling to work out what to do next.

Does anybody know why the error is happing and how to stop it?

Answer (score 6):

I also got the same error with a vite project that's communicating with an api server through docker. The problem was that the IP address of the api in my .env was wrong. It is fixed, once I changed my variable with the correct value/ IP. Does your app somehow make a request prior to the initiation of your app? If yes, you may want to check the address you are requesting to. If the problem still occurs, I would suggest to:

1. Delete `node_modules`
2. Run `npm cache verify` to make sure there are no other problems.
3. Run `npm install`