# I get an error when I connect with the https module in the API I created with Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http, https

I wrote an API for my website's contact form using Node.js, I host the API on AWS Lightshail, I got my SSL certificates from Cloudflare for free, and after 5-6 hours after starting the API, an error appears in the console, this error does not prevent the API from running. But I can't find the cause, if anyone knows the solution, I would be grateful if you could help me.

```js
(node:5532) Warning: An error event has already been emitted on the socket. Please use the destroy method on the socket while handling a 'clientError' event.
    at warnUnclosedSocket (node:_http_server:839:11)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnError (node:_http_server:853:5)
    at onParserExecuteCommon (node:_http_server:888:19)
    at onParserExecute (node:_http_server:809:3)
```

### UPDATE

I added an option to my code to print the error to the console and I got a bunch of different errors.

```js
server.on("clientError", (error, socket) => {
    console.log(error)
});
```

```js
[Error: A00D0000:error:0A00010B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\record\ssl3_record.c:355:
] {
  library: 'SSL routines',
  reason: 'wrong version number',
  code: 'ERR_SSL_WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER'
}
Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:217:20) {
  errno: -4077,
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read'
}
Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:217:20) {
  errno: -4077,
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read'
}
[Error: A00D0000:error:0A0000C1:SSL routines:tls_post_process_client_hello:no shared cipher:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\statem\statem_srvr.c:2241:
] {
  library: 'SSL routines',
  reason: 'no shared cipher',
  code: 'ERR_SSL_NO_SHARED_CIPHER'
}
Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:217:20) {
  errno: -4077,
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read'
}
Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:217:20) {
  errno: -4077,
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read'
}
[Error: A00D0000:error:0A000102:SSL routines:tls_early_post_process_client_hello:unsupported protocol:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\statem\statem_srvr.c:1677:
] {
  library: 'SSL routines',
  reason: 'unsupported protocol',
  code: 'ERR_SSL_UNSUPPORTED_PROTOCOL'
}
Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:217:20) {
  errno: -4077,
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read'
}
Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:217:20) {
  errno: -4077,
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read'
}
[Error: A00D0000:error:0A0000C1:SSL routines:tls_early_post_process_client_hello:no shared cipher:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\statem\statem_srvr.c:1762:
] {
  library: 'SSL routines',
  reason: 'no shared cipher',
  code: 'ERR_SSL_NO_SHARED_CIPHER'
}
[Error: A00D0000:error:0A00006C:SSL routines:tls_parse_ctos_key_share:bad key share:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\statem\extensions_srvr.c:646:
] {
  library: 'SSL routines',
  reason: 'bad key share',
  code: 'ERR_SSL_BAD_KEY_SHARE'
}
```

`server.js`

```js
const express = require('express');
const chalk = require("chalk");
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');

const app = express();
const options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('./ssl/private-key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./ssl/certificate.pem'),
};

const server = https.createServer(options, app);
server.listen(443, () => {    
    console.log(chalk.magenta(`[API]: `) + chalk.green('PORT : [ 443 ]'))
});
```

`package.json`

```js
{
  "name": "contact-api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Contact API",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
    "chalk": "^4.1.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "deep-email-validator": "^0.1.21",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "express-rate-limit": "^6.7.1",
    "figlet": "^1.6.0",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "https": "^1.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "nodemailer": "^6.9.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: just for the record, you posted a warning, not an error

Comment: Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76652485/how-to-stop-a-random-node-error-node196569-warning-an-error-event-has-alre?

Comment: Hi James, I saw it and did as instructed but to no avail.

Comment: At a quick glance, the code you've provided doesn't use 8 of the dependencies you've required, and you could dump chalk very easily. Please provide a [mcve] - emphasis on the minimal. Don't make people install piles of modules that aren't needed to solve the problem or make edits to your code just to run it.

Comment: Hi Quentin, you are really right. Sorry, I'm editing the code. Thanks for your message.

Comment: Please add your `package.json` file content to your question.

Comment: Hi xgqfrms, I have attached my package.json file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### There are some problems with your codes.

- First, you are using many old packages as dependencies, which may have some mutual incompatibility issues.
- Secondly, you might be using the wrong `key.pem` and it's not being decrypted.
- Thirdly, you didn't provide an API endpoint and with some wrong config of the certificate, so you got a lot of client error messages in the console.

1. for the `wrong version number` error, check out your `SSL`/`TSL` version;
2. for the `unsupported protocol` error, find out what `protocol` be used;

### Try following my minimal demo code to fix your problem.

```js
// 1. use the latest version package with `ES modules`
import https from 'node:https';
import fs from 'node:fs';
import express from 'express';
import chalk from 'chalk';

const app = express();
const port = 443;
const options = {
  // 2. must use decrypted `key.pem` ✅
  key: fs.readFileSync('./decrypt_key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('./cert.pem'),
};

// 3. you need to create an API endpoint
app.get(`/api`, (req, res) => {
  console.log(`req`, req.query);
  res.json({
    https: true,
    port,
  })
});
// https://localhost/api?id=1

const server = https.createServer(options, app);
server.listen(port, () => {
  const color = chalk.green.bgGreen('Hello world!');
  console.log(`color log`, color);
  console.log(`https server is running on: https://localhost:${port}/`);
  console.log(chalk.magenta(`[API]: `) + chalk.green('PORT : [ 443 ]'));
});

server.on("clientError", (error, socket) => {
  console.log(`clientError`, error);
});
```

> enabled ESM by adding `"type": "module"` to your `package.json` file

```json
{
  "name": "express-https",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "https",
  "type": "module",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./server.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "https",
    "node.js"
  ],
  "author": "xgqfrms",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "chalk": "^5.3.0",
    "express": "^4.18.2"
  }
}
```

### OpenSSL

```bash
# generate key
$ openssl req -x509 -sha256 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365

# get the decrypt key
$ openssl rsa -in key.pem -out decrypt_key.pem
```

### demo and screenshot

https://localhost/api?id=1

[image]

Comment: use command `$ openssl req -x509 -sha256 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365`
to generate a key, then use use`$ openssl rsa -in key.pem -out decrypt_key.pem` to get the decrypt key.

Comment: Use my simplified code first to make sure you resolve the HTTPS issue. Then gradually add and test your other dependent packages to ensure that each package is working properly.

Comment: Hello, after my recent tests, the code you wrote works perfectly! The API works much faster than before, I appreciate your help.  +1