# Node Warning: An error event has already been emitted on the socket. Please use the destroy method on the socket while handling a 'clientError' event

Tags: node.js, typescript, vuejs3

I created a new Vue 3 app using the following options:

```
npm create vue@latest

✔ Add TypeScript? … Yes
✔ Add JSX Support? … No
✔ Add Vue Router for Single Page Application development? … Yes
✔ Add Pinia for state management? … Yes
✔ Add Vitest for Unit testing? … No
✔ Add an End-to-End Testing Solution? … No
✔ Add ESLint for code quality? …  Yes
✔ Add Prettier for code formatting? … Yes
```

When running `npm run dev`

The application runs as usual:

```
  VITE v5.0.10  ready in 300 ms

  ➜  Local:   http://localhost:5173/
  ➜  Network: use --host to expose
  ➜  press h + enter to show help
```

But when navigating to the localhost it crashes and shows this error:

```
(node:51508) Warning: An error event has already been emitted on the socket. Please use the destroy method on the socket while handling a 'clientError' event.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

When running the app using `--host` it shows

```
  VITE v5.0.10  ready in 295 ms

  ➜  Local:   http://localhost:5173/
  ➜  Network: http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:5173/
  ➜  Network: http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:5173/
  ➜  Network: http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:5173/
  ➜  press h + enter to show help
```

And navigating to one of the networks URLs works just fine.

I'm using `Node 20.10.0 64bit` but I've tried multiple versions without any luck.

- How can I debug this?
- If you are familiar with this error, how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

A few general ideas:

1. I think there's a chance there's something weird going on with Node v20.10.0. I think Node v20.11 is out for LTS, so possibly try that? Ref: [Github Node Issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/51073)
2. This [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76652485/how-to-stop-a-random-node-error-node196569-warning-an-error-event-has-alre/76866109#76866109) post suggests checking the IP address for your Vite configuration

In general, if it was me, I would try playing around with different versions of Node or Vite and see if there's a bug with any one of those specific versions for now.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried your suggestions, unfortunately didn't work out. I tried multiple Node and Vite versions, I will try some more if I have the time

Answer (score 0):

The error you encountered in your app seems to be related somehow to low-level network issues in the Node.js server. Try to update to the latest version also update your project dependencies using 'npm install' command.
After that you can try to update Vite with 'npm update vite'.

I believe you already tried that so the next thing you can try is to check for network or firewall issues on your local host.

If that didn't work you can always try using another port to make sure it's not a problem with the port that's causing this error.

You can check the browser console for further info that might help you solve your problem, and make sure you browser extensions aren't causing the problem by disabling them.